# Authentication failed Error when deploying to AWS EC2 AMI with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma, net-ssh

I am following this tutorial:

```
https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/
```

The app is fully created and running in development (including the database).
Keys have been added to GIT and SSH, although from the tutorial I am very sure which of them goes exactly where.

And this the error I am getting.

```
$ gem list net

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (3.2.0, 3.1.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
contactbook liviu-mac $ cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook
** Invoke rvm:check (first_time)
** Execute rvm:check
cap aborted!
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@52.87.233.215
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:249:in `start'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:155:in `with_ssh'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:108:in `execute_command'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:60:in `capture'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/Users/liviu-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rvm:check
```

I attempted almost all fixes suggested in the posts I found. Nothing works for me.

Here are more details:

```
$ gem list net

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (3.2.0, 3.1.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
```

My Capfile is:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/puma'
# require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'capistrano/ssh_doctor'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

My `config/deply/production.rb` file is (one single uncommented line):

```
server '52.87.233.215', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

And my `config/deploy.rb` file is:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.6.1'

set :application, 'contactbook'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:levi-l-damian/contactbook.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp
set :branch, :master

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/contactbook'

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system'
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.3.1' # Edit this if you are using MRI Ruby

set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"    #accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, false
```

Don't know how to fix this and move forward?

Comment: What happens when you run `ssh -v deploy@52.87.233.215`?

Comment: I will edit the question to provide the details but in the essence I am getting Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Sorry, looks like I don't have edit privilege, don't know how to send full details?

Comment: The final part is:
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/liviu-mac/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/liviu-mac/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/liviu-mac/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/liviu-mac/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/contactbook.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-226-156-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com
su - deploy
chmod 400 /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown deploy:deploy /home/deploy -R
```

Only after that the commands:

```
ssh -v deploy@54.226.156.103
```

and

```
cap production deploy
```

succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

When troubleshooting `authentication failed` errors in Capistrano, it is useful to drop down to a lower level and test connectivity with `ssh` first. That way you can figure out if it really is a Capistrano problem, or a more basic SSH connectivity issue.

In this case Capistrano says it cannot connect to `52.87.233.215` as the `deploy` user. Let's verify that manually like this:

```
ssh -v deploy@52.87.233.215
```

The `-v` flag dumps a bunch of verbose logging so that we can see what authentication methods are being attempted.

If you get `permission denied (publickey)`, that is an indication that you do not have your public key properly installed on the server. In other words, the server has no way of verifying you are who you claim to be, and denies access.

To install your public key, copy the contents of this file *from your local machine*:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And paste those contents into this file *on the server*:

```
~deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Make sure that `~deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys` is owned and accessible by the `deploy` user:

```
$ ls -ld ~deploy/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x 2 deploy deploy 4096 Jun 16  2015 /home/deploy/.ssh
$ ls -ld ~deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 deploy deploy 1023 Sep 12 02:13 /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now try the `ssh` command again:

```
ssh -v deploy@52.87.233.215
```

It should work, and if so, Capistrano should now work as well.

Comment: Looks like here is  the problem:

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-60-174 ~]$ su - deploy
Password: 
Last login: Thu Sep 22 15:36:10 UTC 2016 on pts/0
[deploy@ip-172-31-60-174 ~]$ ls -ld .ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy 407 Sep 22 15:31 .ssh/authorized_keys
[deploy@ip-172-31-60-174 ~]$ ls -ld .ssh
drwx------ 2 deploy deploy 4096 Sep 22 02:58 .ssh

How I should change the this to match your "drwxr-xr-x "?

Comment: OK, I did this:

[deploy@ip-172-31-60-174 ~]$ chmod -R 755 .ssh
[deploy@ip-172-31-60-174 ~]$ ls -ld .ssh
drwxr-xr-x 2 deploy deploy 4096 Sep 22 02:58 .ssh

Comment: And now this is working:

ssh -v deploy@52.87.233.215

Comment: But I am getting this now: Permissions 0755 for '/home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open. And I am locked out from the server when using this (that worked before): $ ssh -i ~/.ssh/contactbook.pem ec2-user@ec2-52-87-233-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Something may be be ok with my EC2 instance, I will destroy it and recreate it.

Comment: I destroyed and recreated the instance. I have these now:

$ ls -ld ~deploy/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x 2 deploy deploy 4096 Sep 22 20:05 /home/deploy/.ssh

$ ls -ld ~deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy 407 Sep 22 19:41 /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys

But this fails:
$ ssh -v deploy@54.226.156.103

debug1: Authenticating to 54.226.156.103:22 as 'deploy'

Comment: debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:pKqZHRGwWnmAx0GRemOIuXSew8DNu+x/KZebAWoQO2o
debug1: Host '54.226.156.103' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/liviu-mac/.ssh/known_hosts:30

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/liviu-mac/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/liviu-mac/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/liviu-mac/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).